# Confusion about Joint Probability

Tags: probability

**Scenario 1:**

From a deck of 52 cards, the joint probability of picking up a card that is both red and 6 is

By Counting : 2/52 = 1/26

By using multiplication rule : P(6)×P(red)= (4/52 × 26/52) = 1/26

**Scenario 2:**

| Planned to Travel | Travelled | Did Not Travel | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | 200 | 50 | 250 |
| No | 100 | 650 | 750 |
| Total | 300 | 700 | 1000 |

The Joint Probability of people that plan to travel and actually travelled is 200/1000 = 0.2

**Question:**

Why is the Joint Probability of people that plan to travel and actually travelled is not

P(Plan to travel) x p(Travelled) = 250/1000 x 300/1000 = 75/1000

Can some math guru please explain me.

Comment: For the cards denomination and color have independent distributions. For travel, it seems that planning to travel is a prerequisite for traveling.

Comment: Hi: These things are easy for BruceET so if it's not obvious, think of it this way. In scenario 1, if you have a 6, that gives you no info about color ( and vice versa ) so you can multiply the probabilities of the events and get the same answer because the events are independent. In the second scenario, whether you actually travel is not independent of whether you plan to travel so the events are not independent so multiplying the probabilities of the individual events is incorrect..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The joint probability of event $A$ and $B$ is defined as
$$
P(A,B) = P(A|B)P(B) = P(B|A)P(A).
$$
This could be understood intuitively as the occurrence of either $A$ or $B$ might influence the probability of the other happening (called dependent events). Scenario 1 is a special case, in which the occurrence of either event does not affect the probability of the other (A and B are independent events), i.e. there are the same number of 6s that are red compared to those that are in other individual colors, so
$$
P(A|B) = P(A) \Rightarrow P(A,B) = P(A)P(B).
$$
But the same is not true for the second scenario. There is dependency in the data such as there are more people in the “planned to travel” category that travelled. So to calculate the joint probability mathematically, we have to multiply P(Planned to travel given travelled) by P(travelled). The formula for the conditional probability is given by
$$
P(A|B) = \frac{P(A,B)}{P(B)}
$$
which already has $P(A,B)$ in the numerator, so in this type of scenario, the joint probability is rarely calculated multiplicatively.